# untracked and deleted at the same time (git)

Tags: git

I have converted an old hg repository into git with hg-fast-export.sh. Then I've copied the .git directory into the server filesystem. I would expect git to recognize that all the files are the same as expected. Instead git complains that all the files are both `deleted` and `untracked`. For example:

```
$ git status base.html
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    base.html

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    base.html

$ git diff base.html
$ ls -al base.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 crm crm 673 Sep  2  2016 base.html
$
```

What is happening? How can I fix this?

I don't want to run the risk of removing and regenerating all the files on the server.

Comment: Why did you copy the `.git` directory? Why did you not initialise the server repo and then `git push` the newly converted repo there?

Comment: to preserve history and ignored files

Comment: Ignored files are maintained in the `.gitignore` file (or whatever you've specified as your ignore file). The history will be pushed when you push the repository. Copying over the `.git` directory will affect the timestamps on all the files inside it which, I think, affect the index behaviour.

Comment: If I run `git init` on a directory without a `.git` I obtain an empty history... maybe I don't understand your suggestion. The server directory contains a mercurial repository.

Comment: If you want a  working copy on the server, my recommendation would be that you push your code to github/gitlab and then do a clone on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me why the file is showing up as "to be deleted" (note that it's not deleted *yet*, it is *to be deleted* instead) but the rest of the output is quite normal: it just means that somehow, you have told Git that the *next* commit you plan to make should omit the file `base.html`.

To fix this, use the advice shown by Git itself above:

> ```
> git reset HEAD base.html
> ```

The file will now no longer be marked "to be omitted from the next commit".

(Edit: to do this for all files, consider using `git reset HEAD`.  Without a file name this does a `--mixed` reset using the current commit.)

#### Long: how this works

You're coming from Mercurial, which is simpler and a lot easier to use than Git.  There are a few big differences between the two, and the key one in this case has to do with Git's *index*.  First, though, let's mention things that are the same:

- In Mercurial, files stored in the repository are simply files stored in the repository.  These files are stored as permanently as the commits themselves, i.e., they will be there forever unless you explicitly strip out the commits (or use `hg commit --amend` to roll back the last commit and then put in a different one, or otherwise remove commits).

  Git is the same here: there is a database of commits (although unlike Mercurial's database, it's not very database structured).  Those commits are mostly permanent, though you can deliberately abandon them.  In Mercurial you use `hg strip` to remove them; in Git, you abandon them, and then some time later, Git reaps them on its own.
- In Mercurial, you have a *working tree* or *work-tree* in which the files from some commit have been extracted and are available for your use.  The commit from which the files have been extracted is your *current commit* (the *`rev`* from `hg update -r rev`, or whatever).

  In Git, this works almost exactly the same way: your work area has files from the current commit.  The current commit is named `HEAD` instead of `.`, though you can use `@` if you prefer that.
- Not all files in the working tree need be present in the current commit.  These are *untracked files* and some of them may also be *ignored* (via `.hgignore`).  If an untracked file needs to become a tracked file—which will then go into the next commit—you use `hg add`.

  In Git, the mechanism here is different and the file is named `.gitignore` but the same general rules apply: you can have files that are untracked.  If an untracked file needs to become a tracked file, you can use `git add`.  However, since the underlying mechanism is different, there may be other commands you can use as well (as is the case here).

The key difference that you have encountered at this point is that in Mercurial, the *work-tree itself* is your proposed next commit.  You simply change some file in the work-tree, and `hg status` tells you that the file is modified.  The next `hg commit` builds the new commit from the work-tree.<sup>1</sup>  In Git, however, the *proposed next commit* is **not** your work-tree.  It is a separate structure that Git calls *the index*, or *the staging area*, or sometimes—rarely these days—the *cache*.

This thing, this index or staging area—both names refer to the same thing—holds a *copy of every file that will go into the next commit*.<sup>2</sup>  A file in Git is *tracked* if and only if there is a copy of it in the index.  If you *remove* the index copy—which doesn't affect any existing commit (it can't) and doesn't affect your work-tree either (the index is not your work-tree)—then the file is scheduled to be *left out* of the next commit.  Your proposed next commit, in other words, is whatever is in the index *right now*.

The presence and use of this index is why, in Git, you have to keep `git add`-ing a file every time you modify it.  In Mercurial, the proposed next commit *is* your work-tree, so if you modify a file in your work-tree, you've updated the proposed next commit.  In Git, you have to tell Git *copy my updated work-tree file back into your index*, which you do with `git add`.  Now the modified file is in the index, ready to be committed, so *now* the proposed next commit has the updated file.

In your particular case, the file `base.html` has somehow been removed from the index.  So when comparing the current commit to the index, Git says *`base.html` would be removed, if you commit now*.  Since the file isn't in the index, but is still in your work-tree, Git also says that the file is untracked, because that's precisely what it means to have an untracked file: it's not in the index, but is in your work-tree.

So, all you have to do is copy some version of the file back into the index.  The command `git add base.html` will copy your work-tree copy of the file back into Git's index.  The command `git reset HEAD base.html` will copy the current-commit (`HEAD`) copy of the file back into Git's index.  If these two copies of the file match, it won't matter which command you use: both will restore the file to the index, after which `git status` will say nothing at all about `base.html`.

---

<sup>1</sup>There is a bit of subtle trickiness here with *missing* files in Mercurial, which are not automatically removed.  You can also tell Mercurial not to commit some updates; I'm only covering the typical use cases here.

<sup>2</sup>Technically, the index does not have a copy of the file, but rather a reference to a Git internal blob hash ID.  But unless you start messing with the `git update-index` and `git ls-files --stage` commands, you don't really need to know that: you can think of the index as holding a full copy, ready to be committed.  Git *shares* identical copies of files through this underlying *blob object* mechanism, which is how Git de-duplicates the many copies of files that are repeatedly committed without changing them.  (Mercurial has a different trick that works about as well.)

Comment: Thank you for the solution and the long answer! So, to understand, in normal situations after a commit the index contains all committed files. The conversion script, instead, has left the index empty.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini: that indeed seems to be the case. Probably the conversion software should fill the index at the end of its work, but given that it's a one-time thing, it's perhaps not that important. :-)